# Could not resolve placeholder in string value with external files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-properties

I have configured a config.xml file choosing the appropriate properties file depending on environment. I am running this as a Spring Boot app with Apache Camel.

The config looks like this.

```
<bean id="properties"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="locations" ref="locations" />
</bean>

<bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder"
    class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" ref="locations" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>

<beans profile="dev">
<util:list id="locations">
    <value>classpath:config/users.properties</value>
    <value>classpath:config/application.properties</value>
    <value>classpath:config/application-dev.properties</value>
</util:list>

<beans profile="test">
<util:list id="locations">
    <value>file:${project.dir}/config/users.properties</value>
    <value>file:${project.dir}/config/application.properties</value>
</util:list>
```

When using the test profile I want to use the external files defined in the config (because I dont want to commit username/password to repo). That seems to work okay.

However, my users.properties file contains:

```
username=myusername
password=mypassword
```

and my application.properties contains:

```
loginParameters=username=${username}&password=${password}
```

when running `java -jar myjar.jar --spring.profiles.active=test` I encounter:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'username' in string value '${username}&password=${password}'
```

It clearly loads the properties files because it states:

```
Loading properties file from URL: file:...../users.properties
Loading properties file from URL: file:...../application.properties
Bridging Camel and Spring property placeholder configurer with id: bridgePropertyPlaceholder
...
```

And then the exception occurs. How can I resolve the issue where the application.properties file doesn't recognize my properties defined in users.properties? Everything works okay when running the dev-profile.

Answer (score 0):

in your application properties, use $simple{username} and $simple{password} to tell Camel to put the values there.